# How can I make a Jenkins build for a GitHub repository be triggered by a push to a different repository?

Tags: python, github, jenkins

I have a GitHub repository (call it X) for a Python code package, and a separate GitHub repository (call it X-tests) that contains the tests for that package (they're separate repositories because the one containing the tests is private so that it can run other private code).  I would like to make it so that when someone pushes to the X repository, Jenkins will run the tests from the X-tests repository, and then do some other stuff related to the X repository (e.g. making a pip wheel).

The only way I can think of to do this is to have three separate Jenkins jobs:

1. a job that does nothing, whose GitHub repository is X, where builds are triggered by pushes to X
2. a job that runs the tests, whose GitHub repository is X-test, where builds are triggered by completion of job 1
3. a job that makes the pip wheel etc., whose GitHub repository is X, where builds are triggered by completion of job 2

Is there any simpler way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a pretty standard approach to implementing a simple *build-test-posttest* pipeline. Job 1 is *name*-commit-stage, job 2 is *name*-test-stage or name-integration-stage and a third job for your pip-wheel.

You can see a more complex pipeline in the [build pipeline jenkins](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Pipeline+Plugin) plugin.

Check if your third job should be using job 1's artifacts instead of repository X. This will bring atomicity to your pipeline as someone could push something to your repository X while a job has already started. The [Copy Artifact Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Copy+Artifact+Plugin) is useful for that, or you can just reference the local job 1 workspace as a source of your job 3 (as a parameter in a build step).

You also need to make sure that changes to repository X-Tests should be pushed before changes to repository X, as job 2 may use code in repository X-Tests that is not in sync with repository X, leading to test failures.

Comment: Oh okay.  Can you explain how to make job 3 use job 1's "artifacts" (or just, the state of the repository at the time job 1 was run)?